# OwlCarousel Youtube video not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, owl-carousel

I have a youtube video that I want shown but it doesn't show at all. I didn't add a height or width to video because I want to keep it responsive.

http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/video.html

```
<div id="carousel" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oy9GFAQ4x4w"></a>
  </div>
  <div><img src="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/7a7a5814-ed79-410c-b748-db6a24f73f0b/4d71c010-f930-4334-ba62-79d87a7ddef4.jpg"></div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nLz17fcv/12/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a video using `a` tag Seems not working.

```
<div>
    <a class="owl-video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oy9GFAQ4x4w"></a>
</div>
```

Instead it you can replace it by `Iframe` to embed the video you want like this.

```
<div class="item-video">
   <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Oy9GFAQ4x4w">
   </iframe>
</div>
```

In addition to, I've removed   `transitionStyle: "fade"` because this property blocks the carrousel transition.

You can check it on this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nLz17fcv/18/)

Hope It Helps

Comment: Can I make the video responsive? I'd like to not specify a height or width to the iframe.

Comment: Yes, you can make the video responsive just changing the css properties whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

In my case the error were with the URL that was being generated while creating iframe, I placed "https://" in front of Youtube iframe and changed few things as (Added "https:")

```
<pre>
if (video.type === 'youtube') {
html.attr( 'src', 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + video.id );
} 
else if (video.type === 'vimeo') {
html.attr( 'src', 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/' + video.id );
}
</pre>
```

One more thing I did for vimeo video was added "https:"

```
<pre>
url: 'https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' + video.id + '.json',
</pre>
```

Comment: doing this I had one problem that the new iframe was loading again when I clicked on the "Play - Pause" button, Therefore I did this thing, somewhere in line number 2210 :

` 'changed.owl.carousel': $.proxy(function(e) {
if (e.namespace && e.property.name === 'position' && this._playing) {
this.stop();
$('.owl-video-play-icon').hide();
}
}, this),
`
**$('.owl-video-play-icon').hide();**